# Mysql complex statement, min & max from 2 columns, in 1 row

Tags: mysql, row, max, min

And again, could any Mysql expert help me with Mysql statement?
What i have: 2 tables connected with foreign keys userid and balanceID [image]

What I need: I need to find row where is MAX value of lets say debt and MIN value of lets say loan, What i expect from this statement is to find highest value debt and the lowest loan (1 row) for example : in this case it would be row name2 | 200 | 40. Is that possible? Have done research and couldnt find solution, any help appreciated.

Comment: What if the highest debt and lowest loan aren't in the same row?

Comment: I don't see how the tables are related.

Comment: thats the point I need to find max and min in a single row, I mean "most high available where most low available in a ROW" ;] tables are related by foreign by id`s;] anyways thats not the case, lets say, I need the statement for 1 table, dont pay attention to 1) one.

Comment: You'll need to answer the question from @lc. then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess based on your minimal data set, but perhaps something like:

```
select top 1 balanceID, balance, debt, loan
from Balance
order by debt - loan desc
```

If you want to group by `UserID`, something like:

```
select b.balanceID, b.balance, b.debt, b.loan
from Balance b
inner join (
    select UserID, max(debt - loan) as MaxDebt
    from Balance
    group by UserID
) bm on b.UserID = bm.UserID and (b.debt - b.loan) = MaxDebt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` the two tables with the minimum loan and maximum balance only from the second table like so:

```
SELECT u.name, t.balance, t.loan
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table2 
    WHERE balance = (SELECT MAX(balance) FROM table2)
      AND debt    = (SELECT MIN(loan) FROM table2) 
 ) t ON -- JOIN condition
```